# How to extract specific data from csv file and insert into mysql database using python and notepad++

Tags: python, csv

I want to create a page which allows a user to upload their csv file. Once the user has submitted the csv file, a python code will then insert the data into the table in the phpMyadmin database.

I have an excel file which has been exported to a csv file. The file contains 12 columns but I only wish to insert 2 of the columns into the phpMyadmin database. The problem is when I click the submit button, I come across a page showing my code. How can I successfully upload the csv file and extract the relevant data I need from the file to insert it into the database? Any help is much appreciated.

[image: This is the page I see when I click the submit button]

Here is the code for the form which allows the user to upload the csv file:

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4>Upload your CSV file</h4>
    <form method="POST" action="class_list_upload.py" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name="file" required></p>
      <br><br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit file</button>                    
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the python code which I found online that helps to insert it into the database:

```
    import pandas as pd 
    import pyodbc

    # Import CSV
    data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\wamp64\www\FYP2021\sample name list.csv')   
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Module Group','AdmNo'])
    print(df)

    # Connect to SQL Server
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=localhost;'
                          'Database=login;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Insert DataFrame to Table
    for row in df.itertuples():
        cursor.execute('''
                    INSERT INTO login.dbo.users (username, tg, user_type, password, EGF1)
                    VALUES (?, ?, user, 12345, 1)
                    ''',
                    row.Module Group, 
                    row.AdmNo,
                    )
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: `phpMyadmin` is an administrative tool, not a database. How Notepad++ is involved with your problem?

Comment: No I meant the database in the phpMyadmin. As for the notepad++ I was trying to say that I am using Notepad++ for the editor. Sorry for the wrong sentence structure.

Comment: Oops... In order to use a Python script server side, you first have to setup a web server able to launch it. If you just browse a local folder, or use a non Python script enabled http server, you will see the source and nothing will be executed server side. I am sorry, but configuring Apache + mod_wsgi, or even cherry.py or flask is far beyond what I can write on SO...

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for that! I shall stick to using php then. :)